# Google Analytics report api v4: how to get Visit Duration

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-reporting-api

Is anybody knows how to get **Visit Duration** from Google Analytics report api v4?

I'm trying to find information in Dimensions & Metrics Explorer: 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets
But I don't see anything like that..

**Updated:**

I tried:

**ga:sessionDuration** - Total duration (in seconds) of users' sessions.

**ga:avgSessionDuration** - The average duration (in seconds) of users' sessions.

The result:

sessionDuration = "7.1339069E7",

avgSessionDuration = "322.4262946807236"

As far as I understand, it should be vice versa:
sessionDuration is total, so it shoud be at least bigger than avgSessionDuration..
Also **avgSessionDuration** looks like what I need..

Thanks!

Comment: While I have never seen the API return scientific e notation I have to say that 7.1339069E7 (which is 7.1339069 multiplied by 10 to the power of 7) seems to be larger than 322 and a bit.

Comment: Oh, exactly! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`ga:sessionDuration`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=session&jump=ga_sessionduration) which refers to total duration (in seconds) of user's sessions.

Also, you may want to regularly check [Google Analytics Reporting API Changelog](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/changelog) to be fully updated with the addition and renaming of dimensions and metrics that are already supported. Based from the changelog, `ga:visitDuration` was renamed to `ga:timeOnSite` then, was updated to `ga:sessionDuration`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
I tried:
ga:sessionDuration
ga:avgSessionDuration
The result:
sessionDuration = 7.1339069E7 
avgSessionDuration = 322.4262946807236
As I understand, it must be vice versa:
sessionDuration is total, so it shoud be at least bigger than avgSessionDuration.. Maybe I do not understand something?
Thanks!